# Keep all the Accordion options visible but open/close or collapse one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have a custom Accordion, which has by default all the options in **"Visible/Open"** state.

When I click first time, it close the particular element. But when I click it again, it open that particular element but close rest all.

**It should collapse and open One element ata time.**

Here is my Accordion code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='accordionmenu' class="clear">
<ul class="grid-18">
    <li class="inputRow active"> <a href='javascript:;'><h2 class="first">Heading #1</h2></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="grid-8">Content for heading 1</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="inputRow active"> <a href='javascript:;'><h2 class="first">Heading #2</h2></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="grid-8">Content for heading 2</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="inputRow active"> <a href='javascript:;'><h2 class="first">Heading #3</h2></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="grid-8">Content for heading 3</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#accordionmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
 $('#accordionmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
     var checkElement = $(this).next();
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
         checkElement.slideUp('normal');
     }

     if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
         $('#accordionmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
         checkElement.slideDown('normal');
     }

     if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 });
```

**Here is the Fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/XLw2Z/**

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: Comment this line `$('#accordionmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');`

Comment: That was quick... It worked, can you please post it as an answer? it will help someone in future...

Comment: strange, i did try commenting it though, and everything stopped working then..  but i made some more changes, maybe due to that... but quick n good learning... +1

Comment: Posted an answer, may i ask why you input this line if you did a custom accordion? :P

Comment: initially the requirement was to a default accordion condition so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is responsible for the other accordion to toggle :

```
 if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
     $('#accordionmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
     checkElement.slideDown('normal');
 }
```

By commenting the line `$('#accordionmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');`. Everything work like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/5vG9Z/

```
 $('#accordionmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
 $('#accordionmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {

     $(this).next().toggle('slow')

     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, it does solve my purpose, but when it close, all the content in <LI> slides left and then the box colapse, I just made the change which "Karl-André Gagnon" suggested in his comment.. and it works.. Thanks once again!!!